# Select tables for display column as rows

Tags: sql-server, select, pivot, sql-server-2019

I have follow statement:

```
select ID,
       Systemname,
       Mode,
       Evtdate,
       Sattus,
       Desc
From dbo.MainTasksStatus;
```

```
ID  SystemName Mode EvtDate Status  Desc
----------------------------------------------------------
125  Almo   Mode1   9/29/2023 9:11:00   TRUE    Complete All        
126  Almo   Mode2   9/28/2023 11:14:00  FALSE   Not Complete
127  Almo   Mode3   9/29/2023 10:28:00  TRUE    Complete Partial        
237  Dido   Mode2   9/27/2023 8:14:00   TRUE    Complete All    
238  Dido   Mode3   9/28/2023 12:48:00  TRUE    Complete Partial        
315  Faroon     Mode1   9/27/2023 9:11:00   FALSE   Not Complete
316  Faroon     Mode3   9/28/2023 15:22:00  TRUE    Complete All
```

As you can see, the records are based on the systemName. Systems are related to three Modes(Mode1,Mode2,Mode3) . some systems have all three modes and some have some of them.

I want select to produce the following output
[image]

In the search, I noticed that this is done with pivot, but I don't know exactly how to create this output.

Comment: This is a job for your presentation layer, not the SQL layer.

Comment: I'm also surprised that statement works; `DESC` is a reserved keyword and should therefore cause a syntax error.

Comment: Definitely a presentation layer issue in this case. If you read the `PIVOT` documentation you'll have noticed that it can only work with columns of a single data type whereas you have several types involved here.

Comment: Manual conditional aggregation pivot should make this a no-brainer. The base structure is `MAX(CASE WHEN somecolumn = somedesiredvalue then columnToPivot END)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with finding out what the names are and then left join a record from each mode to them.

Test sample:

```
create table something(name varchar(32), mode varchar(32));

insert into something(name, mode)
values
('a', 'Mode1'),
('b', 'Mode2'),
('c', 'Mode3'),
('d', 'Mode1'),
('d', 'Mode3'),
('e', 'Mode1'),
('e', 'Mode2'),
('e', 'Mode3');
```

Query:

```
select t.name, t1.Mode as Mode1, t2.Mode as Mode2, t3.Mode as Mode3
from (select distinct name from something) as t
left join something t1
on t.name = t1.name and t1.Mode = 'Mode1'
left join something t2
on t.name = t2.name and t2.Mode = 'Mode2'
left join something t3
on t.name = t3.name and t3.Mode = 'Mode3'
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2e215/13

Result:

[image]

One can also run a single scan with conditional aggregation as @Thom A pointed out in the comment section. I have implemented and tested the idea, reaching this query:

```
select name,
       max(
         case
             when Mode = 'Mode1' then Mode
         end
       ) as Mode1,
       max(
         case
             when Mode = 'Mode2' then Mode
         end
       ) as Mode2,
       max(
         case
             when Mode = 'Mode3' then Mode
         end
       ) as Mode3
from something
group by name;
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/2e215/14

Comment: Thanks for answer, but This select displays systemNames that have all modes and does not display those that lack some modes

Comment: @a.Paryab did you do a `FULL OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: yes, i execute your select exactly.

Comment: @a.Paryab you are right, looking into it

Comment: @a.Paryab applied changes and now I actually tested the query over a fiddle, it yielded the results I wanted. You can replace the sample table I have used with yours and adjust the columns. If you have difficulties while doing so, please create a Fiddle and put there your current try and link it to this comment section. If this answer solved your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Lajos , this is right, Thanks for your help

Comment: @a.Paryab happy to help!

Comment: I would suggest the problem is the efficiency of the query. You retrieve data from the table, `something` *four* times, and one of those with a `DISTINCT`. The same results could easily be achieved with a *single* scan and conditional aggregation.

Comment: @ThomA thanks for the comment. Added a single-scan solution with conditional aggregation to my answer along with proof-of-concept. It may be useful if performance issues happen, but, if more columns are needed from each dimension, then the conditional aggregation might become repetitive. It's up to the reader to decide what fits best their scenario. But thanks again for the comment, it's good to have something to improve upon.